# how to format the html date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, datepicker

The format in my html date picker is as yyyy-MM-dd  [image: as displayed in the picture]

but when i pass the same field to the backend it does not pass with the same format  it passes something like `*/*/Sun Mar 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Arab Standard Time)`

i want it to to pass the same format which is specified in the date picker 
thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with angular?

Comment: i am using angular as my JS ' may be some changes in JS will make it workable.

Comment: I see. You have to format the date before you send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to format the date before it gets sent to the server (and you're using vanilla JavaScript - without libraries like [moment](https://momentjs.com/)), you can do it as follows:

```
dateObj.getFullYear() + "-" + (dateObj.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dateObj.getDate()
```